# The deployment is transitioning since 2 hours

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-deployment

After a deploy started from VS2012, my deployment stuck in status "transitioning".  Actually, my services are working properly, and all instances are running.

I cant update, delete, or stop my deployment.

Any suggestion?

Thanks,
T

Comment: If you use the old Management Portal you may be more successful. Btw it's a nice case for filing a support request.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is you hit a race condition bug on the portal who was coordinating the tenant state and Fabric Controller (kernel of windows azure). Normally you can safely ignore this behavior, but if you prefer to fix this permanently and does not care if your service go down for a while, you can choose to delete the entire deployment and start over. This will likely cause your service to be allocated onto different servers or even different clusters. Please note this is different from redeploying from visual studio which will likely cause Azure to reuse the existing servers.

Or, you can simply call Azure customer service and escalate this issue. They will mitigate your issue and provide proper root cause analysis.